# Finding Least and Greatest for one array in a two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

So, this is an assignment from school that I've been trying to figure out how to make work...

I have two different arrays going: One with strings, the other with integers.

After getting user input on how much of each salsa was sold, I then needed to:

1. Create a properly-formatted table showing how much of each salsa was sold
2. Show the total amount of all salsas sold
3. Show what was the most amount of salsa sold and which was the least amount.

It compiles just fine, but it keeps spitting out strange answers for Least and Greatest salsas sold.

I'm not quite sure how to make this work... What's the right way to tackle this?

Thank you for any input in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
string salsa[5] = {"mild", "medium", "sweet", "hot", "zesty"}; //x-values
int jars[5] = {0}; //y-values

        cout << "\nHow many jars of mild salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[0];
        while (jars[0] < 0)
        {
            cout << "\nHow many jars of mild salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[0];
        }

        cout << "\nHow many jars of medium salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[1];
        while (jars[1] < 0)
        {
            cout << "\nHow many jars of medium salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[1];
        }

        cout << "\nHow many jars of sweet salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[2];
        while (jars[2] < 0)
        {
            cout << "\nHow many jars of sweet salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[2];
        }

        cout << "\nHow many jars of hot salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[3];
        while (jars[3] < 0)
        {
            cout << "\nHow many jars of hot salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[3];
        }

        cout << "\nHow many jars of zesty salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[4];
        while (jars[4] < 0)
        {
            cout << "\nHow many jars of zesty salsa were sold?: ";
            cin >> jars[4];
        }

        cout << left;
        cout << "\n" <<
        setw(7) << "[Spice] " << setw(6) << "       [Jar]" << '\n' <<
        setw(7) << salsa[0]   << setw(10) << " " << jars[0] << '\n' <<
        setw(7) << salsa[1]  << setw(10) << " " << jars[1] << '\n' <<
        setw(7) << salsa[2]   << setw(10) << " " << jars[2] << '\n' <<
        setw(7) << salsa[3]  << setw(10) << " " << jars[3] << '\n' <<
        setw(7) << salsa[4]   << setw(10) << " " << jars[4] << '\n' << "\n";

cout << "Total sales: " << jars[0] + jars[1] + jars[2] + jars[3] + jars[4] << "\n\n";


//------------------------------------------------


    int highest;
    highest = jars[0];
    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        if (jars[count] > highest)
            highest = count;
    }

    int lowest;
    lowest = jars[0];
    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        if (jars[count] < lowest)
            lowest = count;
    }

//------------------------------------------------

    cout << salsa[highest] << " was sold the most." << "\n";
    cout << salsa[lowest] << " was sold the least." << "\n\n";

return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
How many jars of mild salsa were sold?: 2

How many jars of medium salsa were sold?: 4

How many jars of sweet salsa were sold?: 6

How many jars of hot salsa were sold?: 8

How many jars of zesty salsa were sold?: 10

[Spice]        [Jar]
mild             2
medium           4
sweet            6
hot              8
zesty            10

Total sales: 30

zesty was sold the most.
sweet was sold the least.

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

It should be saying "mild" was sold the least, not "sweet".

Comment: could you show us your expected output along with the actual output you're getting?

Comment: Yes, let me do that!

Comment: Should now look good. Output added!

Comment: *It compiles just fine,* -- This means nothing really.  All that means is that there are no syntax errors -- it has nothing to do with whether your program contains logical bugs or not.  -- *What's the right way to tackle this?* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler, or learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: *It should be saying "mild" was sold the least, not "sweet".* -- The program does exactly as what you told it to do.  So it should be saying exactly as what you see now.  If it should say something different, then there are bugs in your code.  This is why "compiling fine" really didn't mean anything.

Comment: `lowest = jars[0];` -- See what I mean?  The program did exactly what you told it to.  See anything wrong with this line?  What does `lowest` mean?  The lowest index, or the lowest amount?  Got mixed up?

Comment: There isn't any 2 dimensional array here.

Comment: Not related to your immediate question, but having a line of code to print each separate line of your table is not such a great idea. What if you need to print 5000 lines? Same about input. It would need even more lines.

Comment: And another thing. What if the user makes a mistake and types something that is not a number? Can your program cope?

Comment: I'm still learning basics like syntax and how to make more efficient code. This is for a first-semester class. I'm here to learn. :)

I did put in a verification for negative values, but not a verification for values that are anything other than an integer. I'll look into putting that in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small mistake in your code. Change your code as below. I think I dont need to give more explain with my code because it is very simple!

```
int highest;
highest = 0;
for (int count = 1; count < 5; count++)
{
    if (jars[count] > jar[highest])
        highest = count;
}

int lowest;
lowest = 0;
for (int count = 1; count < 5; count++)
{
    if (jars[count] < jars[lowest])
        lowest = count;
}
```

Note: You just need to travel the array from index 1. checking at index 0 is an exuberancy.

Comment: This one works brilliantly! Thank you! I figured I needed to start at 0... Didn't know it was supposed to be at 1. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your logic. You have this:

```
    int lowest;
    lowest = jars[0];
    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        if (jars[count] < lowest)
            lowest = count;
    }
```

I'd advise you to use this (saving the index and the value separately works as you want. It's similar to the idea of a pointer):

```
    int lowest_value = jars[0];
    int lowest_index = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        if (jars[count] < lowest_value) {
            lowest_value = jars[count];
            lowest_index = count;
        }
    }
```

And then if you want to retrieve the the least value you can use the "lowest_value" variable and if you want to retrieve the index you use the "lowest_index" variable.

Also, i'd advice you to use the name "index" or "idx" or "i", instead of count, 'cause you're not counting.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: exactly, but you just need to travel the array from index 1. checking at index 0 is an exuberancy.

Comment: Yup. But it still works fine with exuberancies as simple as that one. However, i just read your solution and I like it more than mine. Thanks.

Comment: Also took a look at using yours. It also works although it's ever so slightly more complex. Thank you for your explanation, though! It really elucidated this bit of logic for me.